# Print month names into the view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to create a ul>li list of month names in rails from Jan to Dec.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#">Jan</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feb</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mar</a></li>
      ...
</ul>
```

So I'm thinking of going through a simple 1..12 loop, but I can't seem to find what method actually gets me these names! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get month names in

```
 Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.dup.slice(1,12)
```

assign them in array and loop through

**EDIT**
**controller**

months =  Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.dup.slice(1,12)

**view**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<% months.each do |month| %>
  <li><a href="#"><%= month %></a></li>
<% end %>

</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I've been looking for!